# How does Genshin Impact judge area completion percentage?

Tags: genshin-impact

When zooming the world map out a bit, smaller places are merged into a location with a completion percentage. I've noticed that these percentages are part of the Travelers reputation in that region.

Here is an example of two locations in Mondstadt

[image: Map showing Starfell Valley at 64% and Galesong Hill at 100%]

What exploration things do I need to do to boost my exploration percent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the things that contribute (might have missed some):

- unlocking Statues of seven
- unlocking teleports
- unlocking domains
- collecting oculli (i.e. anemoculus)
- collecting mora boxes in water (I don't think there's any in Mondstat, they appear in other regions though)
- opening chests (some chests give more completion, specifically shrine of depths ones)

Do keep in mind that even if it shows 100% you might still have stuff missing in the area

Comment: When you say opening chests, do you mean any? Like guarded chests & puzzle chests? I bet I'm missing some chests then!

Comment: @DavidYell yes all chests contribute